# How to show sum of multiple inputs with AngularJS ng-Model?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

This app allows user to enter the quantity of questions for specific topic inside a workbook. I’m trying to sum up all the questions and give an output of totalQuestions.

I created a function (findTotalQuestions().) that will run when Quantity input box is changed. I’m getting an error in Console:  Cannot read property 'quantity' of undefined. I’m thinking its because $scope.skill.quantity is not being passed into function. How can I fix this?

```
<div class="input-field col m3" ng-model="totalQuestions">
   <medium>Total Questions in Workbook: </medium>{{totalQuestions}}
</div>
```

**HTML**

```
<table>
     <tr>
        <th> Skill </th>  
        <th> Quantity </th>
     </tr>
     <tr ng-repeat="skill in newWorkbook.skills">
         <td>
            { skill.topicText }}
         </td>
         <td>
              <p>
                <input id="quantity{{ skill.TopicId }}" type="number" class="validate" ng-model="skill.quantity" required="true" autocomplete="off" ng-change="findTotalQuestions()">
              </p>
         </td>
       </tr>
 </table>
```

**Controller:**

```
$scope.getProposedSkills = function() {
  return $http.get("/api/topics?SubjectId=" + $scope.newWorkbook.SubjectId).then(function(skills) {
    return $scope.newWorkbookskills = _.map(skills.data, function(skill) {
      var obj;
      obj = {
        TopicId: skill.id,
        quantity: 0,
        level: null,
        topicText: skill.topicText,
        startLevel: skill.startLevel,
        endLevel: skill.endLevel
      };
      return obj;
    });
  });
};

$scope.findTotalQuestions = function() {
  $scope.totalQuestions = 0;
  $scope.totalQuestions = $scope.totalQuestions + $scope.skill.quantity;
  return console.log($scope.totalQuestions);
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your `getProposedSkills()` code in a service then in the controller set the  `$scope.skill` like below

```
app.service('service',function($http){
    return {getProposedSkills:$http.get('your api url')};
})
```

Your controller should look like below

```
app.controller('ctrl',function($scope,$http,service){
   $scope.getProposedSkills = service.getProposedSkills().then(function(res){
       $scope.skill=res;
   })      

  $scope.findTotalQuestions = function() {
     $scope.totalQuestions = 0;
     $scope.totalQuestions = $scope.totalQuestions + $scope.skill.quantity;
     return console.log($scope.totalQuestions);
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

And other question i can't find the place where you set $scope.skill in your controller, 
if it's a paremeter to be used in your funcion, you should receive it as a paremter of your function and pass it form the view
if it's a variable on your controller it should be initialized or at least check if it exists.

By the way, In the html you have a div with ng-model, this is not correct ng-model should be place inside form inputs (select, input, textarea)

Comment: $scope.skill was determined in the controller, i didn't include it in the question. I wasn't sure if it was necessary to include it. thanks for the advice. i will update my ng-model.